# Show kernel version on two lines in Conky

Tags: kernel, conky

I use 3 different kernels: 5.19.1-xanmod1-x64v2, 5.19.1-051901-generic, and 5.18.0-17.1-liquorix-amd64.
Conky uses $kernel to display the full kernel version I'm using at the time.
I want to to display the info on two lines like so:

5.19.1

xanmod1-x64v2

5.19.1-051901

generic

5.18.0-17.1

liquorix-amd64

I can get the first part by using ${exec uname -r | sed "s/ *-[a-z].*//"} but can't figure out a way to get the second part.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's considerably more complex, but the command

```
sed 's/\([0-9][\.0-9]*\)\([-0-9][\.0-9]*\)\?-\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3/'
```

outputs info for each of your kernels on two lines, as shown below.

```
[David@Fedora64 ~]$ echo 5.19.1-051901-generic | sed 's/\([0-9][\.0-9]*\)\([-0-9][\.0-9]*\)\?-\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3/'
5.19.1-051901
generic
[David@Fedora64 ~]$ echo 5.19.1-xanmod1-x64v2 | sed 's/\([0-9][\.0-9]*\)\([-0-9][\.0-9]*\)\?-\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3/'
5.19.1
xanmod1-x64v2
[David@Fedora64 ~]$ echo 5.18.0-17.1-liquorix-amd64 | sed 's/\([0-9][\.0-9]*\)\([-0-9][\.0-9]*\)\?-\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3/'
5.18.0-17.1
liquorix-amd64
```

Comment: Thank you that works.  I just had to modify it a bit for conky.  $alignr${exec uname -r | sed 's/\([0-9][\.0-9]*\)\([-0-9][\.0-9]*\)\?-\(.*\)/\1\2\n\t\3/'}